# How to append audio recording at specific position to existing audio recording using Web Audio API?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api

How can i append new recording to selected or particular position in existing recording?

For example, there is recording of 5 sec and i want to record again but appending this recording to previous recording at it's particular position say it: appending this recording after previous recording's length of 3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the buffer data with getChannelData(), then manipulates as your're pleased. Beware of the sample rate!!! You need to understand the relation between sample rate => bufferdata => time.